# I can't select text by worlds

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I'm work with linux mint and I have this issue: when I click ctrl+shift+left or right arrow my text is not selecting by words. And if I click only shift then text is selection by character.

Comment: Have you mapped any global shortcuts to the shift+ctrl+left combination? Can you confirm there are no mappings? Also what is the behavior when you use that combination? What does it do instead of selecting text?

Comment: I have bind only ctrl+shift = language change. shift+ctrl+left combination - do nothing only skip text by words;

Comment: So, if you do Ctrl+Shift+Left do you see the keyboard change? If so, try mapping the KBD change to another combo, and then try to select text.. as  Ctrl+Shift on it's own might be interfering..

Comment: It's work for me!